# Using evil-mode with a function that does not work well with evil-mode

Tags: org-mode, evil

The great org-mode has a fast way to jump between headings in an org file; `M-x org-goto` or `C-c C-j`. This doesn't work with evil mode that well.

If I am on evil normal mode in an org file, `C-c C-j` gets me the `org-goto` interface alright but I stay in normal mode. The same happens if I'm in insert mode. Even when I'm in Emacs state.

It is after the invocation of `C-c C-j` when I have to manually intervene and jump into Emacs state by myself in order to have the functionality work as intended. When I'm finished there, I stay in Emacs state, which I do not desire.

I had these two obvious tries with the machinery but evil ignores both methods. I'm in normal mode, no matter what.

```
;; No go
(defun progo-org-goto ()
  (interactive)
  (call-interactively 'evil-emacs-state)
  (call-interactively 'org-goto))

;; no go; but the advice did run.
;; also tried "after"
(defadvice org-goto (before goto-advice activate)
  (message "adviced goto")
  (call-interactively 'evil-emacs-state))
```

So what kind of magic do I have to perform to have evil change to Emacs state during the `org-goto` and then return to normal mode afterwards?

Comment: "So what kind of magic do I have to perform to have evil...?" As Arthur C. Clarke would say, "Sufficiently advanced technology".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your instincts were right on advising `org-goto`, but you want around advice rather than before advice.  The following advice should do what you want:

```
(defadvice org-goto (around make-it-evil activate)
  (let ((orig-state evil-state)
        (evil-emacs-state-modes (cons 'org-mode evil-emacs-state-modes)))
    ad-do-it
    (evil-change-state orig-state)))
```

It saves your current state in the `let`-bound `orig-state`, temporarily adds `org-mode` to `evil-emacs-state-modes` so that `*org-goto*` (whose major mode is `org-mode`) will be opened in `emacs-state`, runs the regular `org-goto` function via `ad-do-it`, and then restores your original state.

Comment: That's what I'd missed when trying to find the answer, was trying to set the state rather than default to `evil-emacs-state` for `org-mode` temporarily.  Should also be more future-proof in case the buffer name were to be changed somewhere.

Comment: Glad to help.  Quick note: fixed a silly bug in the code: the `push` changed the list in place and left `org-mode` in the `evil-emacs-state-modes` list after finishing the function call.  Swapping `append` in for `push` allows us to clean up after ourselves properly.

Comment: Sigh.  Or, if we'd like it to be cleaner and easier on the eyes, use `cons` in place of `append`.  The code now reflects this.

Comment: Indeed, this is slightly less hacky so better promote this.

Answer (score 4):

`org-goto` creates a new buffer named `*org-goto*` when you use it. Therefore, you can check for this name with a hook, using something like:

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda ()
                           (if (string= "*org-goto*" (buffer-name))
                               (evil-emacs-state))))
```

Comment: Fantastic! thanks so much. I had this question on SU for months, nothing. Moved it here and took 15 mins :)